# Class / Method not returning the correct value

Tags: c#, console, console-application, windows-console

Probably a pretty newb question but here we go.

I am quite new to this and right now i have reached my first logic problem i guess.

I've created a class + method which is supposed to return me a Int32 value and it returns something that is, atleast in my eyes, unreachable. I also dont want this value to be returned.

Here's the code:

```
    public static Int32 SetInterval(ConsoleKeyInfo cki)
    {
        if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D1 || cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D2 || cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D3 || cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D4 || cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D5 || cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D6)
        {
            if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D1)
            {
                return 10000;
            }
            else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D2)
            {
                return 20000;
            }
            else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D3)
            {
                return 30000;
            }
            else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D4)
            {
                return 45000;
            }
            else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D5)
            {
                return 60000;
            }
            else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D6)
            {
                return 120000;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            SetInterval(Console.ReadKey());
        }
        return 50;
    }
```

And here is how i execute it within my main class:

```
        static int interval;

        interval = DefineInterval.SetInterval(Console.ReadKey());
        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine(interval.ToString());
```

So whats happening now is:

If i press one of the 6 numbers correctly without pressing any other key before, its just fine. The output is normal and as it's supposed to be.

Then again, when i press, for example "a6" on my Keyboard all i get is:

"
a6
50
"

Any ideas? Also probably not the best way to do such a thing.

Comment: That looks like the output I would expect... are you intending to `return SetInterval(Console.ReadKey())` from the `else` block?

Comment: you can remove your outer if statement, it isnt doing anything

Comment: Consider using a `switch` statement too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recursive call to `SetInterval` in the `else` block doesn't do anything with the return value.  What you want is this:

```
public static Int32 SetInterval(ConsoleKeyInfo cki)
{
    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D1)
    {
        return 10000;
    }
    else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D2)
    {
        return 20000;
    }
    else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D3)
    {
        return 30000;
    }
    else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D4)
    {
        return 45000;
    }
    else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D5)
    {
        return 60000;
    }
    else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D6)
    {
        return 120000;
    }
    else
    {
        return SetInterval(Console.ReadKey());
    }
}
```

Note that I also moved the unnecessary if statement surrounding the first else if chain.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Int32 SetInterval(ConsoleKeyInfo cki)
{
    if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D1 || cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D2 || cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D3 || cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D4 || cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D5 || cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D6)
    {
        if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D1)
        {
            return 10000;
        }
        else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D2)
        {
            return 20000;
        }
        else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D3)
        {
            return 30000;
        }
        else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D4)
        {
            return 45000;
        }
        else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D5)
        {
            return 60000;
        }
        else if (cki.Key == ConsoleKey.D6)
        {
            return 120000;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return SetInterval(Console.ReadKey());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are recursively calling your method. When you give correct input, it goes fine.

**Else** it goes to get correct input, and after that correct input it returns the default value from the first call of the method.

**Solution:**

Just remove the `return 50` and set:

```
else
{
    return SetInterval(Console.ReadKey());
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Quick question- why would you press "a6" ? is it by mistake and you want this to be read as just 6 by your program and move on or is there a different reason behind it? If that is the reason then you need to remove the return 50 and place return SetInterval(Console.ReadKey()) in else.